# Skrollr causing intervention error and changing element.style of body and html to overflow: hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, skrollr

I'm trying to use skrollr on my website, but when I include needed files and write script tags at the end of my html file console write this error everytime when you try to scroll: `skrollr.min.js:2 [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080` and it changes `element.style` of body and html to `overflow: hidden` and it is impossible to scroll on that website. Can you help me how to prevent that ? Everything works fine when you just remove skrollr.js from that  file.

Answer (score 0):

Add an override to your main css file:

```
body, html {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I did that, but why is it happening when it's total bul****t